# How to filter array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I have a JSON data. I am pushing this data to another array. The problem  i am facing is, i want to filter array whose data `attrs` has `src` property. And push these array to another array. Can anyone will help me in this.I am not getting a way to do this.

**My Json data is like:**

DATA:

```
[
 {
  "data":{
},
   "type":"image",
    "attrs":{
     "x":92,
     "y":163,
     "width":100,
     "height":100,
     "src":"http://localhost:63342/wodrobs/app/scripts/views/img/top.jpg",
   "cursor":"move",
   "opacity":1
   },
     "transform":"",
   "id":0
},
{
   "data":{
   },
   "type":"path",
   "attrs":{
   "fill":"none",
   "stroke":"#000",

     "stroke-dasharray":"- ",
    "opacity":0.5
  },
   "transform":"",
   "id":17
},
```

]

Comment: Can you post your real data, above is invalid.

Comment: Real data is too large. Anyway I am posting.

Comment: @dfsq i have posted real data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. i was doing silly mistake.

```
 var filterData= _.filter(jsonData, function (data) {
            return data.attrs.src;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your pseudo-json, you can do like this:

```
//your data
var a = [
          {'src':"a.src"}, 
           {'id':"someid"},
          {'src':"b.src"} 
];

//the result array
var result = [];


for(i=0; i<a.length;i++){
  var e = a[i];
  if(e.src){
    result.push(e);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

http://jsbin.com/hujicopuca/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
function HasSrcProperty(value, index, ar) {    
    return value.some(elem => elem.indexOf("src") > -1)    
}
var result = yourJsonArray.filter(HasSrcProperty);
```

For more info on javascript array `filter` and `some`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679973%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some